# http.request for the url http://freegeoip.net/json/14.12.111.113

Tags: node.js, http

Hi i am trying to write a node server code to retrieve longitude and latitude information from the url http://freegeoip.net/json/14.12.111.113 i a always getting this error.

```
Exception: Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND
Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND
    at errnoException (dns.js:37:11)
    at Object.onanswer [as oncomplete] (dns.js:124:16)
```

Can someone help please.

here is code i am using..

```
var options = {    
    host: 'http://freegeoip.net/',    
    path: 'json/14.12.111.113',
    method: 'GET'
};

var req = http.request(options, function(res) {    
    console.log('STATUS: ' + res.statusCode);    
    console.log('HEADERS: ' + JSON.stringify(res.headers));    
    res.setEncoding('utf8');    
    res.on('data', function (chunk) {   
        console.log('BODY: ' + chunk);
    });    
});

// write data to request body

req.write('data\n');
req.write('data\n');
req.end();
```

Comment: Please use code block formatting while posting code...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't add 'http' and the path starts with '/'

```
var options = {    
    host: 'freegeoip.net',    
    path: '/json/14.12.111.113',
    method: 'GET'
};

var req = http.request(options, function(res) {    
    console.log('STATUS: ' + res.statusCode);    
    console.log('HEADERS: ' + JSON.stringify(res.headers));    
    res.setEncoding('utf8');    
    res.on('data', function (chunk) {   
        console.log('BODY: ' + chunk);
    });    
});

// write data to request body

req.write('data\n');
req.write('data\n');
req.end();
```